# Open each subfolder in the folder, open the xls file and insert the images

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with VBA/Excel code. I have one folder with 10 subfolders:

- 10
- 15
- 20
- 25...

Each subfolder has 5 files:

- inserthere.xls
- front.png
- back.png
- left.png
- right.png

I need to insert the 4 images in all the .xls in all the subfolders.

I thought something like this, but I don't have the knowledge of the syntax:

```
read variable path from a cell or
initial_path = "C:/something/";
counter = 10;
i = 1;
for i=1:10
path = initial_path + counter;
open path
open inserthere.xls

insert image 1
insert image 2
insert image 3
insert image 4

i = i + 1;
counter = counter + 5;
end;
```

Thank you in advance for your help :) 
I wish you a great day!

Comment: Just insert them into the xls file anywhere?

Comment: I would like to write the title in a cell (I can do this by myself), then place the image. Or one image per sheet. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice pseudocode - pretty close to the real thing. Here is what I think you're looking for - note, this doesn't insert the pictures in any certain place, they'll probably stack on top of each other if they're the same size as well.

**Only partially tested:**

```
Sub Test()

Dim initial_path As String, new_path As String
Dim i As Long, counter As Long

initial_path = "C:\something\"
counter = 10

For i = 1 To 10
    new_path = initial_path & counter

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=new_path & "\inserthere.xls"

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image1.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image2.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image3.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image4.png")

    'Close and save changes
    Workbooks("inserthere.xls").Close True

    i = i + 1
    counter = counter + 5
Next i

End Sub
```

EDIT: If inserting all pictures into one file:

```
Sub Test()

Dim initial_path As String, new_path As String
Dim i As Long, counter As Long

initial_path = "C:\something\"
counter = 10

Workbooks.Open Filename:=new_path & "\inserthere.xls"

For i = 1 To 10
    new_path = initial_path & counter

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image1.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image2.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image3.png")
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (new_path & "\image4.png")

    i = i + 1
    counter = counter + 5
Next i

'Close and save changes
Workbooks("inserthere.xls").Close True

End Sub
```

This is assuming your `inserthere.xls` file is in the `C:\something\10\` folder location.

Comment: Thank you so much dwirony!
If I want to insert all the images in one .xls I just need to remove this from the for cycle, right? 
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\something\inserthere.xls"

Comment: @JohnKroll I was under the impression that there is a `inserthere.xls` in each subfolder - if you're just trying to loop through the folders to get the images, then you can move that `Workbooks.Open` to outside the loop, open it once, then below the loop move the `Workbooks().Close`.

Comment: If I want to insert image1 (folder 10) in A1 (top left corner), image 2 (folder 10) in A15, image 1 (folder 15) in D1, image 2 (folder 15) in D15? I think I should insert another counter that increase the number of the row for each cycle, right? Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnKroll They're sizing based on the row width? You'll have to use `.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft` and `.ShapeRange.IncrementTop` to get them where you want them - I'd suggest recording a macro to figure out exactly how to place them.

Comment: @JohnKroll I would suggest opening a new question with how to position your images once they've been inserted - there are too many factors here for me to know how to your pictures, like where your `ActiveSheet` is focused when you open the file, how big the pictures are and if they're the same size, etc.